# Could something bad happen when sending a delayed response to a USB HID request with a data payload?

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, hid

I'm working on a USB gadget project that uses ConfigFS with the hid function module. I'm using `USB_GADGET_DELAYED_STATUS` for `HID_REQ_GET_REPORT` (HID feature reports).
I have patched the local kernel for my device (Raspberry Pi zero) and added some functionality to *f_hid.c* to get the data I want. I have also commented out the line in **usb_composite_setup_continue** of *drivers/usb/gadget/composite.c* that forces the request length to zero. It appears to work. My device is able to provide a delayed response to a feature request.

**The question I have is**: is there a "bad thing" that could happen by sending a data payload in a delayed USB HID reponse? The delays are sub-millisecond, and allow the data for the response to be retrieved.

The reason I ask is *composite.c* has a warning that `USB_GADGET_DELAYED_STATUS` only works for zero length responses.

```
else if (value == USB_GADGET_DELAYED_STATUS && w_length != 0) {
    WARN(cdev,
        "%s: Delayed status not supported for w_length != 0",
        __func__);
}
```

And I already mentioned how **usb_composite_setup_continue** forces the length for a delayed request to zero. If I comment that out and keep the full request length, I can send my response to `HID_REQ_GET_REPORT` with a full data payload for my application (64-bytes).

I found this note from the [commit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/1b9ba000177ee47bcc5b44c7c34e48e735f5f9b1) that implemented `USB_GADGET_DELAYED_STATUS`

> The DELAYED_STATUS mechanism is currently only supported if the expected data phase
> is 0 bytes (i.e. w_length == 0). Since SET_CONFIGURATION and SET_INTERFACE are the
> only cases that will use this mechanism, this is not a limitation.